# Failed copying input tensor. keras model.fit fails for gpu full

Tags: tensorflow, keras

It seems that the GPU reached the capacity, so how can I handle the training when the dataset is too big?  I tried to call the `fit()` several times giving it just a percentage of the dataset at a time. but it did not work.

The dataset is the tiny-imagenet200 that are 200 folders with 500 images each. each image is 64*64 pixels

The code I use is the following:

```
sizeDS = len(trainClasses)
    for i in range(0,sizeDS-size4train,size4train):
        print("[INFO] Training from {:d} to {:d} of {:d} images...".format(i,i+size4train,sizeDS))
        startindex = i
        endIndex = i + size4train-1
        xTrain = trainImages[startindex:endIndex]
        yTrain = (trainCoordinates[startindex:endIndex], trainClasses[startindex:endIndex])
        hypermodel.fit(x = xTrain, y = yTrain,
                   validation_data=(testImages, (testCoordinates, testClasses)),
                   epochs=best_epoch,
                   batch_size = 5,
                   verbose='progress bar')
```

and the error is as following:

> Mensaje = Failed copying input tensor from
> /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 to
> /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 in order to run
> _EagerConst: Dst tensor is not initialized.   Origen = E:\OfflineRepository\40_Research_offline\80_DeepLearning\DeepLearningClass\practicasX\practicasX\Proj1\Proj1.py
> Seguimiento de la pila:   File
> "E:\OfflineRepository\40_Research_offline\80_DeepLearning\DeepLearningClass\practicasX\practicasX\Proj1\Proj1.py", line 152, in  (Current frame)
> verbose='progress bar')

Currently I implemented it in this way, and it no longer crashes, but I dont know if the training is correct. Do the weights remain between invocations? In my desperation I implemented a `for loop` invoking the `fit()` in data chunks even calling the garbage collector.

```py
      for i in range(0,sizeDS,size4train):
            print("[INFO] Training from {:d} to {:d} of {:d} images...".format(i,i+size4train,sizeDS))
            startindex = i
            endIndex = i + size4train-1
            xTrain = np.ndarray.copy(trainImages[startindex:endIndex])
            yCoord = np.ndarray.copy(trainCoordinates[startindex:endIndex])
            yClass = np.ndarray.copy(trainClasses[startindex:endIndex])
            yTrain = (yCoord,yClass)
    
            hypermodel.fit(x = xTrain, y = yTrain,
                       validation_data=(testImages, (testCoordinates, testClasses)),
                       epochs=best_epoch, 
                       batch_size = 8,
                       verbose='auto')
            time.sleep(1)
            del xTrain
            del yTrain
            del yCoord
            del yClass
            gc.collect()
```